# Error al subir un archivo al servidor desde la web en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un pequeño código para cambiar la imagen de perfil de un usuario. El error que tengo es que no funciona correctamente, no me da ningún error pero la imagen no se sube ni se modifica el atributo en la base de datos.

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
$extensiones = array(0=>'image/jpg',1=>'image/jpeg',2=>'image/png');
$max_tamanyo = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

$ruta_fichero_origen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ruta_nuevo_destino = '../img/Img_profile/' . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
if ( in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $extensiones) ) {
     if ( $_FILES['imagen']['size']< $max_tamanyo ) {
         if($row['Img_user']!=NULL){
            unlink("../img/Img_profile/".$row['Img_user']);
         }
          else{ 
              $var=move_uploaded_file ( $ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino );
              $sql_img = "
    UPDATE usuario
    SET Img_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($_FILES['imagen']['name']) ."'";
$result = $conexion->query($sql_img);

          }
     }
}?>

<form class="form" action="actualizar_formulario.php" method="post" id="registrationForm">
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="img_profile" style="color:white"><h4>Cambiar imágen de perfil</h4></label><br>
            <input  style="color:white" type="file" name="imagen" class="text-center center-block file-upload">
         </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <br>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Guardar</button>
                <button style="color:white" class="btn btn-lg" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Restablecer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola Christian. No me quedan claras varias cosas: Una vez actualizada la imagen, cuando tengas que mostrarla, dónde va a estar la imagen almacenada? De dónde sale `$row`? Qué guardas en la columna `Img_user` de la base de datos?

Comment: la imagen esta almacenada en $ruta_nuevo_destino en mi servidor, la variable $row sale del require include_sesion.php, es un array que contiene todos los datos del usuario que ha iniciado sesion. En la columna Img_user guardo el nombre de la imagen(imagen.jpg por ejemplo).

Comment: Para subir archivos, el formulario debe tener el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: ya lo hicem pero sigue sin subirse la imagen al servidor

Comment: Solucionaste el problema? Comprueba que `file_exists($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])` devuelve `true` y que `filesize($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])` te devuelve el valor esperado. Mira que la carpeta de destino exista y que el servidor web (Apache, Nginx o lo que uses) tenga permisos de escritura.

Comment: He hecho las comprobaciones que propones y todas están correctas, hice un var_dump y el resultado es el esperado, los permisos de escritura están bien y el tamaño también es correcto.

Comment: ¿Vas a permitir más de una imagen de perfil por usuario? ¿Almacenas en alguna variable de sesión u otro lugar el identificador único del usuario? He notado que haces uso de una variable, `$row`, que ya contiene información del usuario en `unlink("../img/Img_profile/".$row['Img_user']);`.

Comment: La idea es que el usuario ponga su foto de perfil y cuando quiera cambiarla borrar la que tiene y poner la nueva. En la array $row almaceno todos los datos del usuario incluido su id($row[id_user]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me fije que te falta añadir `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en el formulario y también en la sentencia sql para actualizar el campo de la tabla usuario te falta declarar el `WHERE` con el id o referencia al registro del usuario en cuestión.

Añadí un ejemplo un poco modificado de tu script PHP. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

```
/**
 * CONFIGURACIÓN
 */
$rutaImagenes = '../img/Img_profile/';

$extensiones = array(0 => 'image/jpg', 1 => 'image/jpeg', 2 => 'image/png');
$max_tamanyo = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

/**
 * IMAGEN
 */
$nombreDeImagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$ruta_fichero_origen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ruta_nuevo_destino = $rutaImagenes . $nombreDeImagen;

if (!in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $extensiones)) {
    exit('La imagen no cumple con el formato permitido.');
}

if ($_FILES['imagen']['size'] > $max_tamanyo) {
    exit('La imagen debe pesar menos de 8 MB.');
}

$imagenSubida = move_uploaded_file($ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino);

if (!$imagenSubida) {
    exit('Se intentó subir la imagen, disculpe las molestias e intentelo mas tarde.');
}

  // Id de usuario de ejemplo.
    $idUsuario = 1;
    // En la sentencia te falta el where para actualizar el registro del usuario en cuestión, añadi un campo "id" de ejemplo, tu añade el tuyo.
$sql_img = "UPDATE usuarios 
                        SET Img_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($nombreDeImagen) . "' 
                        WHERE id=$idUsuario";
$conexion->query($sql_img);

if ($conexion->affected_rows  === 0) {

    if (!file_exists($rutaImagenes . $nombreDeImagen)) {
        exit('No existe la imagen recientemente subida en el directorio');
    }
  
    $sql_img = "UPDATE usuario SET Img_user='" . $row['Img_user'] . "' WHERE id=$idUsuario";
    $conexion->query($sql_img);

    if ($conexion->affected_rows  !== 0) {
        unlink($rutaImagenes . $nombreDeImagen);
    }

    $conexion->close();

    exit('No pudo actualizar la imagen, disculpe las molestias');
}

$conexion->close();

if ($row['Img_user'] != NULL) {
    if (file_exists($rutaImagenes . $row['Img_user'])) {
        unlink($rutaImagenes . $row['Img_user']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay un problema al intentar subir dos fotos con el mismo nombre, en mi caso lo he adaptado para cambiar el nombre de la imagen por el id del usuario así evito el problema del mismo nombre, pero cuando el usuario quiere cambiar la foto como el nombre que pongo con el id es el mismo que la anterior me da error. Porque el row-affected no varia.